# how to read encrypted values from the registry

Tags: c#, encryption, registry

The old method was using an API call.(advapi32.dll). However that is no longer an option. does anyone have an idea how to read encrypted values from the Registry?

Comment: Please elaborate on why calling an API is no longer an option. Saying that you don't want to call an API makes it sound like you are looking for a non-programming solution, which means that it belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: I have read that the advapi32 is no longer available in C# as it was in VB6. I have an app that reads some encrypted Reg values: connection string, User name, PW.....

Comment: advapi32 is still around.

Comment: pinvoke, never used it but it is the only thing i have found to allow the use of advapi32